# Restore from Amazon S3 with dupy - duplicity on a new machine

Tags: backup, centos7, duplicity, duply

I am trying to restore a full backup in a new machine but it seems that is not working.

I installed my pgp's and secret keys. Also I copied my project from duply but when I run

```
duply test restore /tmp/test/
```

I got that:

```
--- Start running command RESTORE at 20:04:19.396 ---
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Warning, found incomplete backup sets, probably left from aborted session
Last full backup date: none
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1502, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1496, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1345, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1430, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 693, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 715, in restore_get_patched_rop_iter
    backup_chain = col_stats.get_backup_chain_at_time(time)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 952, in get_backup_chain_at_time
    raise CollectionsError("No backup chains found")
CollectionsError: No backup chains found
```

Any idea what is the meaning of this no backup chainfs found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone had the same problem than me, I solved using [duplicity-backup](https://github.com/zertrin/duplicity-backup) nice and easy to use!